# Conversion of string value in an array to float in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

Hello friends I have two arrays called

```
var $conversion_rates;
```

and

```
var $LastUpdate_rates;
```

now I am updating them in my class with values . If you do `var_dump()` both of them you get values like this

```
 echo "This is conversion rates<br>".var_dump( $this->conversion_rates = $rates_array);
```

`array(1) { [11]=> float(507.6) } This is conversion rates`

```
echo "This is conversion rates<br>".var_dump($this->LastUpdate_rates = $this->checkRatesFile());
```

`array(1) { [11]=> string(6) "507.60" } This is LastUpdate Rates`

Then I am trying to do is this

```
if( count(array_diff($this->conversion_rates, $this->LastUpdate_rates)) >0){
       //do something ......
}
```

The if statement is always true because the array value are different so I want to change one of the array to float what should I do

Comment: Directly comparing floats with (essentially) `$float1 == $float2` is very prone to errors due to float (in)accuracy to begin with. A simple `array_diff` will probably never get you there.

Comment: Oh so what do you suggest I should do here ?

Comment: On a side note, var_dump() doesn't return a string, it writes directly to stdout. 
If you want it to get a string from it you'll have to use ob. (check php doc of ob_start())

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$a = "0.275";
var_dump($a);
```

Then try this;

```
$a = "0.275";
var_dump((float)$a);
```

And see what you can make of that;